# Matroid Theory with Graph Theory, Need an Introduction Book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matroids

I am looking for a undergraduate introduction to matroid theory. We got them introduced today, to prove the Kruskal algorithm.... I can't say it was more elegant then the direct proof of the algorithm. I also do not see any benefits. Could maybe some explain why matroids are "great", my prof was very very fond of matroids.
I am also looking for an introduction book, maybe with exercises and solutions. (Russian, English, and German are okay.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most standard matroid theory texts feature graphic matroids as examples. James Oxley's survey paper [''What is a matroid?''](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/survey4.pdf) is a great starting place to learn about matroids, and has exercises. For more beyond that paper, Oxley's text *Matroid Theory* is the standard modern reference.

If you're interested particularly in optimization, it is a theorem that matroids are exactly the structures for which the greedy algorithm "works" (just as in Kruskal's algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

Matroids: a geometric introduction by Gordon, McNulty was a good starting point for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1035235)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Well...it kinda does answer the question... **Question.** I am looking for a undergraduate introduction to matroid theory. **Answer.** Matroids: a geometric introduction by Gordon, McNulty was a good starting point for me.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The book I recommended is a Matroid theory book created specifically for undergraduate studies. That's the very first thing Joshua asked for.